# Compare scala.xml.Elem object in unit test

Tags: xml, scala, junit

I have two `scala.xml.Elem` objects (actual, expected). I am using JUnit 4, but have also included XMLUnit 1.3.

Is there any easy way to compare the two objects for equality, ignoring attribute order and insignificant whitespace in the XML?

I tried `XMLUnit.assertXMLEqual()`, but it complains that the types are `scala.xml.Elem`.

I know that I can use `equals` or `==`, but I would like the benefit of having the assertion print the two values when they are not equal. If I use `assertTrue(actual.equals(expected))`, and they are not equal, the only output will be "assertion failed".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the version of `assertTrue` that allows passing custom messages

```
public static void assertTrue(java.lang.String message,
                              boolean condition)
```

and (for example) `diff` to produce the string with the descendand nodes that aren't equal

```
scala> val xml1 = <person><name>john</name><lastname>smith</lastname></person>
xml1: scala.xml.Elem = <person><name>john</name><lastname>smith</lastname></person>

scala> val xml2 = <person><name>jane</name><lastname>smith</lastname></person>
xml2: scala.xml.Elem = <person><name>jane</name><lastname>smith</lastname></person>

scala> assert(xml1 == xml2, xml1.child diff xml2.child mkString(", "))
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: <name>john</name>
        at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:91)
        at .<init>(<console>:8)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
```

Comment: I had considered using assertTrue. I did not know about `diff`. I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to compare to XML `Elem` objects ignoring whitespaces you can remove the whitespaces from them with `scala.xml.Utility.trim` method.

```
scala> val a = <foo>bar</foo>
a: scala.xml.Elem = <foo>bar</foo>

scala> val b = <foo>   bar   </foo>
b: scala.xml.Elem = <foo>   bar   </foo>

scala> a == b
res8: Boolean = false

scala> import scala.xml.Utility.trim
import scala.xml.Utility.trim

scala> trim(a) == trim(b)
res9: Boolean = true
```

Scala does not care about the order of the attributes if you use XML literals:

```
scala> val a = <foo first="1" second="2" />
a: scala.xml.Elem = <foo first="1" second="2"></foo>

scala> val b = <foo second="1" first="1"  />
b: scala.xml.Elem = <foo first="1" second="1"></foo>

scala> a == b
res22: Boolean = true
```

I would recommend [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/) for unit testing there you have the `ShouldMatchers`:

```
// Scala repl started with scalatest-1.2.jar in the classpath

scala> val a = <foo>bar</foo>
a: scala.xml.Elem = <foo>bar</foo>

scala> val b = <foo>bar</foo>
b: scala.xml.Elem = <foo>bar</foo>

scala> a should equal(b)

scala> val b = <foo>bar2</foo>
b: scala.xml.Elem = <foo>bar2</foo>

scala> a should equal(b)
org.scalatest.TestFailedException: <foo>bar</foo> did not equal <foo>bar2</foo>
    at org.scalatest.matchers.Matchers$class.newTestFailedException(Matchers.scala:148)
    at org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers$.newTestFailedException(ShouldMatchers.scala:2329)
    at org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers$ShouldMethodHelper$.shouldMatcher(ShouldMatchers.scala:871)
    at org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers$SeqShouldWrapper.should(ShouldMatchers.scala:1724)
    at .<init>(<console>:15)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$.<init>(<console>:9)
    at RequestResult$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$scala_repl_result(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.Delega...
```

Comment: I was going to post a followup question about trimming whitespace, but your answer covers that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The earlier answers were helpful to me, though I found that sometimes I wanted to check a larger chunk of XML and the failure comparison showing both chunks of XML was a bit hard to read. This method will try to recurse down into child elements first to compare those, so if a deeply nested element is incorrect it will show a much more concise error. Depending on your XML this might not give you enough context to work out where it's actually failing, but I find it useful.

```
/** Check that the XMLs are the same, ignoring empty text nodes (whitespace). */
private def assertEqual(actual: xml.Node, expected: xml.Node) {

    def recurse(actual: xml.Node, expected: xml.Node) {
        // depth-first checks, to get specific failures
        for ((actualChild, expectedChild) <- actual.child zip expected.child) {
            recurse(actualChild, expectedChild)
        }
        actual should be (expected)
    }

    recurse(scala.xml.Utility.trim(actual), scala.xml.Utility.trim(expected))

}
```

Comment: You might want to use `withClue` to provide context, e.g. the shared path of elements containing (i.e. down to) the mismatching pair.

Answer (score 1):

I modified @Nick's code to work with [JDom2](http://www.jdom.org/). In his code, because of how `zip` works, if `expectedXML` has trailing elements that are not in `actualXML`, the test passes. I fixed that bug, and made the comparison of trailing elements optional:

```
trait XMLTest extends XMLSupport {
  /** Verify that the XMLs are the same, regardless of attribute or element ordering and ignoring whitespace. */
  def assertEqual(actual: Element, expected: Element, ignoreTrailingElements: Boolean=false): Assertion = {
    // depth-first comparison
    def recurse(actual: Element, expected: Element): Assertion = {
      import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
      val actualChildren: Seq[Element] = actual.getChildren.asScala.sortBy(_.getName)
      val expectedChildren: Seq[Element] = expected.getChildren.asScala.sortBy(_.getName)
      (actualChildren zip expectedChildren) foreach { case (actualChild, expectedChild) =>
        recurse(actualChild, expectedChild)
      }
      actual.getName shouldEqual expected.getName
      actual.getTextNormalize shouldEqual expected.getTextNormalize
      actual.getAttributes.asScala.map(_.toString).sorted shouldEqual expected.getAttributes.asScala.map(_.toString).sorted
      if (!ignoreTrailingElements && actualChildren.size < expectedChildren.size) {
        val diff = expectedChildren.drop(actualChildren.size)
        fail("Extra XML children found: " + prettyPrint(diff))
      } else succeed
    }

    recurse(actual, expected)
  }
}
```

I wrote this trait to mix into the test code:

```
trait XMLSupport {
  import org.jdom2.output.{Format, XMLOutputter}

  def prettyPrint(doc: Document): String = {
    val xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter()
    xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat)
    xmlOutput.outputString(doc)
  }

  def prettyPrint(elements: Seq[Element]): String = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

    val xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter()
    xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat)
    xmlOutput.outputString(elements.asJava)
  }
}
```

I invoked the test this way:

```
class XmlTest extends WordSpec with MustMatchers {
  // test code here
  assertEqual(actualXML.getRootElement, expectedXML.getRootElement, ignoreTrailingElements=true)
}
```